# How can I reserve an iPhone app name in apple's developer portal?

Tags: iphone

I want to reserve an app name that I intend to build out over the next 90 days, how do I do this in apple's web developer portal?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Update 2015:

The limit of 180 days is now gone, Apple dropped the cap this year -
You can read the full licence [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20140909.pdf), gone.

Also, you may have noticed that the `app name expiring` topic is gone from the `contact us` question tree in iTunes Connect.

That being said, as you can see in the declaration:

> You will not, directly or indirectly, commit ... (e.g., submitting
>   fraudulent reviews of Your own Application or any third party
>   application, choosing a name for Your Application that is
>   substantially similar to the name of a third party application in
>   order to create consumer confusion, or squatting on application names
>   to prevent legitimate third party use.

This lets us suppose that if you haven't updated your binary for a looong time and someone wants to use the same name, chances are that if they ask for it, they will get it, but yeah, technically speaking, you don't need to worry about this anymore.

### Update 2014:

As stated in the [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1), the limit is now **180 days**:

> ***Note***: After you create your app and assign it a name, you have 180
>   days to deliver a binary or else your app will be deleted from iTunes
>   Connect so that the app name is free for use by the developer
>   community. Per section 3.2 of the iOS Developer Program License
>   Agreement, squatting on an app name to prevent legitimate third-party
>   use is prohibited. For information about email alerts you will receive
>   to remind you of this policy, see “App Name Expiry.”

Comment: Can't find the quoted info from the linked page.

Comment: I cant find the qouted info also.. I only found this _Note:  Per section 3.2 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, squatting on an app name to prevent legitimate third-party use is prohibited._

Comment: Apple have apparently changed their policy and removed the limit entirely. It is impossible to find an official source, but this blog post quotes an email from Apple saying "App name expiration is no longer a feature of our program": http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/

Answer (score 16):

90 days you say? This wouldn't be the first project that was supposed to take 90 days but needed more.

Once you fill in the information in itunes connect you have 120 days. After these 120 days your app name will become available for other developers. Yes, others, you can't take it again.

So you better make sure that you have your app ready for sale in 120 days.

You should read the [itunes connect developer guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf). It explains the process in detail. It's too complicated to answer this in a 5 minute stackoverflow answer. But the others outlined it, and I just wanted to mention = the 120 day limit. Happy squatting.

Comment: Definitely check out the iTunes Connect Developer Guide mentioned above. Note, it looks like Apple has raised the limit to 180 days.

Comment: FYI: link to the 'App Name Expiry' section in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide for more information about the maximum amount of time you can reserve an App name: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW20

Comment: It is 180 days. Confirmed yesterday at Apple Tech Talks London :)

Answer (score 9):

You don't do it in the Developer Portal, you do it in **[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)**.

1. **Log in** using your developer credentials
2. Click **Manage Applications**
3. Click **Add New Application**
4. Complete the **basic information**, including the app name

Answer (score 3):

[This resources implies that app names no longer expire](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/).

Answer (score 3):

**TUTORIAL: RESERVE YOUR APP NAME FOREVER**

1. Log in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Click Manage Your Apps
3. Click Add New Application
4. Complete the basic information, including the app name
5. Upload temporary icons and screenshots (for iPhone 4 & iPhone 5)
6. Change the app status to “Waiting for Upload”
7. Create a very simple app and use the new bundle ID
8. Submit the App to the App Store for Review (as you normally would)
9. After the status has changed to “Waiting for Review” go into iTunes Connect
10. Click Manage Your Apps > View Details > Binary Details
11. Click Reject this Binary

This will set the status of your application to “Developer Rejected”. Since you have successfully submitted a binary and had a “Waiting for Review” status it can sit in that status forever, therefore your app name is parked forever! Apple considers it a “real” app since it was officially submitted. So now sit on your great app name until you’re ready to finish development.

([Source 1](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-reserve-your-app-name-forever/), [Source 2](http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/))

Answer (score 0):

In iTunes Connect, go to Manage Your Apps and then Add New App. You can choose a name and enter other relevant information, but not upload binaries at this point. You'll also be able to set a release date in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Go to iTunes Connect, then Manage Your Apps, then Add New App.

Create an App with placeholder data (you'll need screenshots, real or temporary).

If you don't upload an associated production [App Store] distribution App within 90 days, you'll lose the right to use that name forever.

Cyber-squatting on an App name you don't make use of is bad form.

If you decide you don't want to use the name, please delete it and free it up to someone who will.

Comment: App name squatting is much less of an issue now that you have to submit an actual app within 120 days and if you don't, not only do you lose the name but you can never use it again; it becomes available only to other developers.

Comment: Hi there, I've tried to reserve my app name. However, Itunesconnect asked me to upload the logo and screenshot of the app. I understand that the screenshot is changeable, does the logo can be changed later as well?

Comment: Yes, you can change the logo, or any of the other meta data (except the numeric app ID).

Answer (score -1):

You can add the application as suggested above. And about app name reservation here is my answer.

After creating your app and it is in the state Prepare For Upload or Waiting For Upload, you have 180 days (6 months) from your creation date in iTunes Connect to deliver a binary to Apple. If you do not deliver a binary before the 180-day deadline, your app is deleted from iTunes Connect. As a result of this deletion, your app name can be used by another developer and you cannot reuse the app name, SKU or bundle ID.

I got this information from apple documentation and the link is

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW1

Search for "App Name Expiry" and it leads you to the required page.

I hope this helps all of us.