# App name reservation in app store through itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

if I am successfully able to create an app with a name "ABC" in **ITunes Connect**, does this guarantee that name is reserved for me for **180 days**? I have not submitted the app for review. all i have done is fill in bundle id etc. and clicked Save. 
What if another apple developer creates an app with same name "ABC" in itunes connect? will apple prevent it to be used or is it a matter who "submits for review" first ?

Comment: http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/

Comment: By creating app entry in iTunes connect, you can reserve app name. Check This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282723/app-name-already-exists-in-itunes-connect?rq=1

Comment: let me provide more detail.
1- i can check the availability of name in **app store** while creating the app in itunes connect , this part is clear. 
2- the question is, if I successfully create the app in itunes connect with a particular name, is it a guarantee that the name is not taken by an already non-submitted app by some other developer. What happens if someone else had already made an itunes connect app entry with same name

Answer (score 1):

yes, this name is reserved for you and no one can create new iTunes connect app with the sam name.

Also the limit of 180 days is gone according to the following links:

- http://blog.salsitasoft.com/apples-new-app-name-reservation-policy/
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21429

Comment: Also you can check the accepted answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084900/how-can-i-reserve-an-iphone-app-name-in-apples-developer-portal